# how to get record selected from db with selected="selected"

Tags: php

I want to get records from database to fill form for update. I dont have problem with the input fields but for the select option. I want to click on an icon to fetch the data to fill the select option with the selected="selected" base on a specific ID from the db.  Please help.

Thanks

```
 <select name="cat_id">
           <option></option> 
          <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account_type");
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo$row['cat_id']?>" selected="selected" >
<?php echo$row['category']?></option>;
         <?php } ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: What is the error message(s) you are getting?  From the code above it looks like you are simply querying the DB without connecting.  Also, the mysql_* family of functions is deprecated.  You should seriously consider switching to mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<select name="cat_id">
<option></option> 
<?php 
$cat_id = 4; // The selected cat
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account_type");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if($row['cat_id'] == $cat_id) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></option>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']?>"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="cat_id">
<option></option> 
<?php 
$cat_id = 1; // The selected cat
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account_type");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>" <?php if($row['cat_id'] == $cat_id) { echo "selected"; ?>><?php echo $row['category']; ?></option>
<?php   
}
?>
```